# Serializing div

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to make kinda WISYWIG editor that creates a `div` with some inner elements. The `div` (*with all the inner elements structure*), once designed, should be serialized (somehow, hope it's the right term, into string and/or JSON), stored in DB and later inserted to DOM of some other HTML document.

Hence, the questions:

1. Which is the best way to serialize a `div`?
2. Which is the best way to de-serialize a div (and insert it to the DOM)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to grab the HTML code of your DOM elements, you can use `innerHTML`. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5RsM7/1/) for an example:

HTML:

```
<div id='div1'>
  <p>A Paragraph!</p>
  <br/>
  <p>Another p</p>
</div>
<button id='go'>Get HTML</button>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById('go').onclick = function(){ 
  alert(document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't serialize the DIV, you serialize the form fields.

You simply grab the DIV and its contents and store these as HTML directly in the DB. It's basically the same as having HTML in a textarea.

You then just inser the HTML back into the DOM.

Comment: serialization is the "process of converting a data structure or object state into a format that can be stored". You *can* and *do* serialize the DOM, it's called HTML.